# WPF - Making elements disappear as grid starts cutting them of

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I am having a grid with a height that varies. As the height shrinks some of these elements will start getting cut of, resulting in a rather ugly look.

I have experimented with binding the `ActualHeight` of the grid and used a converter to make the elements disappear at a hardcoded height. However, this is rather messy and I wouldn't like to have it hardcoded if it is not really needed.

Are there any other way of tackling this problem? For example, somehow getting the position of elements and comparing them to the grids `ActualHeight`.

Thanks :)

UPDATE, Added xaml code and below a picture showing the issue.

[image: Here, the textbox at row 2 gets cut-of]

For the grid at row three, I've added a converter that returns `Visibility.Hidden` when the grid `ActualHeight` goes below a hardcoded value.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="leafContentTemplate" >
    <Border BorderThickness="5" Background="DimGray">
        <Grid Background="{Binding Tag.PriceChangeDirection, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Name="StockGrid" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <dxe:SparklineEdit Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="100" EditValue="{Binding Tag.Prices}"   Margin="0 5 0 0"  >
                <dxe:SparklineEdit.StyleSettings >
                    <dxe:AreaSparklineStyleSettings AreaOpacity="0.3" Brush="DarkBlue" />
                </dxe:SparklineEdit.StyleSettings>
                <dxe:SparklineEdit.PointArgumentRange>
                    <dxe:Range Auto="True"/>
                </dxe:SparklineEdit.PointArgumentRange>

            </dxe:SparklineEdit >

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Tag.Name}" FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Tag.Ticker}" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="24"/>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Tag.Volume, StringFormat=Vol.: {0}}" FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="Black"  />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"  Text="{Binding Tag.Trades, StringFormat=Trades: {0}}" FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="Black"  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=StockGrid, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightToVisibilityConverter}}" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="100"  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Tag.Price}" 
                       Foreground="White" FontSize="30"/>
                <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  
                       Text="{Binding Tag.PercentPriceChange}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>

                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="&#x25B2;" Visibility="{Binding Tag.IsPosValueChange,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" 
                            Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0"  FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="&#x25BC;" Visibility="{Binding Tag.IsPosValueChange,Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibility}}" 
                            Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you please show code of this issue???

Comment: Added picture and the code for it

Comment: You can use percentage instead of hardcoded values and design UI accordingly.

Comment: Play around with ViewBox. Wrap your TextBoxes inside a ViewBox and set it to shrink only. Then get rid of the auto heights on the rows and use different star settings: 1*, 2*, 4*, etc. this will make it percentage based which will scale better than auto.

Comment: Create regions in your UI.

Toggle visibility of these regions depending upon the Height of the Window.

Use percentage / hard-code values for height accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reusable solution you need two things:

1. The StockGrid's actual height with all it's rows set to Auto height (dummy rows with * height allowed).
2. The height of a grid that acts as a container for your StockGrid. Height set to * (= equal to not set at all).

I stripped your XAML down to the bones

```
<Border BorderThickness="5" Background="DimGray">
    <Grid x:Name="Container">
        <Grid x:Name="StockGrid" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Projector Forsikring" FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="OSL.PROT" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="24"/>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Text="Vol.10000" FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="Black"  />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"  Text="ProTrade" FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="Black">
                <TextBlock.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HeightToVisibilityConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="Container" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="StockGrid" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Visibility>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The IMultiValueConverter

```
public class HeightToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double ContainerHeight = (double)values[0];
        double StockGridHeight = (double)values[1];

        if (ContainerHeight < StockGridHeight)
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        else
            return Visibility.Visible;
   }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that you can take it one step further. Using the sum of the ActualHeights of the Controls in each row, instead of that of the StockGrid's. Each control can then have it's own Converter.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is great, totally solved my issues